# How to make this Javascript work for more than the first element of it's kind on the page?

Tags: javascript

I am making a horizontal scrollable section by clicking and moving the mouse left and right... for desktop users.

It works perfectly fine, but only for the first such section on the page.

I also add a class to the '.item', when mousedown on '.items' . I don't know how to select them to only apply on the specific div that the mousedown is on. (equivalent of jQuery $(this).children('.item') )

Thanks for any help

I am better with jQuery and tried to change the code, but then it didn't work as it was just a mix up of both... also I would like to learn how to make this work with plain JS

```js
const slider = document.querySelector('.items');
const links = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
let isDown = false;
let startX;
let scrollLeft;

slider.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  isDown = true;
  slider.classList.add('active');
  startX = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
  scrollLeft = slider.scrollLeft;
});
slider.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  isDown = false;
  slider.classList.remove('active');
});
slider.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
  isDown = false;
  slider.classList.remove('active');
});
slider.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  if (!isDown) return;
  e.preventDefault();
  const x = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
  const walk = (x - startX) * 3; //scroll-fast
  slider.scrollLeft = scrollLeft - walk;
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].classList.add('noclick');
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item item1"></div>
  <div class="item item2"></div>
</div>
<div class="items">
  <div class="item item3"></div>
  <div class="item item4"></div>
</div>
<div class="items">
  <div class="item item5"></div>
  <div class="item item6"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This includes the code by Alain Cruz with the `sliders.forEach(slider => {..});`. It adds the line `const links = slider.querySelectorAll('.item');` to the last function to get the links only in the slider. It also has CSS to make this code runnable.

```js
const sliders = document.querySelectorAll('.items');
let isDown = false;
let startX;
let scrollLeft;

sliders.forEach(slider => {
  slider.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  isDown = true;
  slider.classList.add('active');
  startX = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
  scrollLeft = slider.scrollLeft;
});
slider.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  isDown = false;
  slider.classList.remove('active');
});
slider.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
  isDown = false;
  slider.classList.remove('active');
});
slider.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  if (!isDown) return;
  e.preventDefault();
  const x = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
  const walk = (x - startX) * 3; //scroll-fast
  slider.scrollLeft = scrollLeft - walk;
  const links = slider.querySelectorAll('.item');
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].classList.add('noclick');
  }
});
});
```

```css
.items {
   background-color: #CCCCCC;
}

.items.active {
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item item1">1</div>
  <div class="item item2">2</div>
</div>
<div class="items">
  <div class="item item3">3</div>
  <div class="item item4">4</div>
</div>
<div class="items">
  <div class="item item5">5</div>
  <div class="item item6">6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

When you use `querySelector` you are only fetching the first item that complies with that selector. You need to change it to `querySelectorAll` and then loop through the fetched elements and assign the event listeners to each one of them.

```
const sliders = document.querySelectorAll('.items');
sliders.forEach(slider => {
    // Your code...
    // slider.addEventListener('mousedown'...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

document.querySelectorAll() should work. Check this example for implementation 
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_document_queryselectorall_loop